# Frequency table with group variable

Tags: stata, frequency

I have a dataset with firm level data.
I have a variable `employees` (an integer) and a variable `nace2` (an integer indicating what industry or service sector the company is related to)

I have created a third variable for grouping employees:

```
gen employees_cat = .
replace employees_cat = 1 if employees >=0 & employees<10
replace employees_cat = 2 if employees >=10 & employees<20
replace employees_cat = 3 if employees >=20 & employees<49
replace employees_cat = 4 if employees >=49 & employees<249
replace employees_cat = 5 if employees >=249
```

I would like to create a frequency table showing how many employees work in every `nace2` sector per `employees_cat`.

As a reproducible example take

```
sysuse auto.dta
```

Let's try to get a frequency table showing the overall mileage (`mpg`) of all domestic / foreign cars that have a trunk space of 11, 12, 16, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starting point for frequency tabulations in Stata is `tabulate` which can show one- and two-way breakdowns. Used with `by:` multi-way breakdowns can be produced as a series of two-way tables. See also `table`.

With the variables you mention in the `auto` data there are 21 distinct values for `mpg` and 18 for `trunk`, so a two-way table would be 21 x 18 or 18 x 21 with many empty cells, as the number of observations at 74 is much less than the product 378. (Here to count distinct values the command `distinct` is installed: `search distinct` in Stata for literature references and latest code version to download.)

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. distinct mpg trunk

------------------------------
       |     total   distinct
-------+----------------------
   mpg |        74         21
 trunk |        74         18
------------------------------
```

One way around this problem is to collapse the tabulation into a list with typical entry {row variable, column variable, frequency information}. This is offered by the program `groups`, which must be installed first, as here:

```
. ssc inst groups 

. groups trunk mpg

  +-------------------------------+
  | trunk   mpg   Freq.   Percent |
  |-------------------------------|
  |     5    28       1      1.35 |
  |     6    23       1      1.35 |
  |     7    18       1      1.35 |
  |     7    24       2      2.70 |
  |     8    21       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |     8    24       1      1.35 |
  |     8    26       1      1.35 |
  |     8    30       1      1.35 |
  |     8    35       1      1.35 |
  |     9    22       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |     9    28       1      1.35 |
  |     9    29       1      1.35 |
  |     9    31       1      1.35 |
  |    10    21       1      1.35 |
  |    10    24       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    10    25       1      1.35 |
  |    10    26       2      2.70 |
  |    11    17       1      1.35 |
  |    11    18       1      1.35 |
  |    11    22       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    11    23       1      1.35 |
  |    11    28       1      1.35 |
  |    11    30       1      1.35 |
  |    11    34       1      1.35 |
  |    11    35       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    12    22       1      1.35 |
  |    12    23       1      1.35 |
  |    12    25       1      1.35 |
  |    13    19       3      4.05 |
  |    13    21       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    14    14       1      1.35 |
  |    14    17       1      1.35 |
  |    14    18       1      1.35 |
  |    14    19       1      1.35 |
  |    15    14       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    15    17       1      1.35 |
  |    15    18       1      1.35 |
  |    15    25       1      1.35 |
  |    15    41       1      1.35 |
  |    16    14       3      4.05 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    16    18       1      1.35 |
  |    16    19       3      4.05 |
  |    16    20       2      2.70 |
  |    16    21       1      1.35 |
  |    16    22       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    16    25       1      1.35 |
  |    17    16       3      4.05 |
  |    17    18       1      1.35 |
  |    17    19       1      1.35 |
  |    17    20       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    17    22       1      1.35 |
  |    17    25       1      1.35 |
  |    18    12       1      1.35 |
  |    20    14       1      1.35 |
  |    20    15       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    20    16       1      1.35 |
  |    20    18       2      2.70 |
  |    20    21       1      1.35 |
  |    21    17       1      1.35 |
  |    21    18       1      1.35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    22    12       1      1.35 |
  |    23    15       1      1.35 |
  +-------------------------------+
```

`groups` has many more options, which are documented in its help. But it extends easily to multi-way tables also collapsed to lists, as here with a third grouping variable:

```
. groups foreign trunk mpg, sepby(foreign trunk)

  +------------------------------------------+
  |  foreign   trunk   mpg   Freq.   Percent |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic       7    18       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic       7    24       2      2.70 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic       8    26       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic       8    30       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic       9    22       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic       9    28       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic       9    29       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      10    21       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      10    24       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      10    26       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      11    17       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      11    22       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      11    28       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      11    34       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      12    22       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      13    19       3      4.05 |
  | Domestic      13    21       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      14    19       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      15    14       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      15    18       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      16    14       3      4.05 |
  | Domestic      16    18       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      16    19       3      4.05 |
  | Domestic      16    20       2      2.70 |
  | Domestic      16    22       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      17    16       3      4.05 |
  | Domestic      17    18       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      17    19       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      17    20       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      17    22       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      17    25       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      18    12       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      20    14       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      20    15       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      20    16       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      20    18       2      2.70 |
  | Domestic      20    21       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      21    17       1      1.35 |
  | Domestic      21    18       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      22    12       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  | Domestic      23    15       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign       5    28       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign       6    23       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign       8    21       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign       8    24       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign       8    35       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign       9    31       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign      10    25       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign      10    26       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign      11    18       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign      11    23       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign      11    30       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign      11    35       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign      12    23       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign      12    25       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign      14    14       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign      14    17       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign      14    18       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign      15    17       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign      15    25       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign      15    41       1      1.35 |
  |------------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign      16    21       1      1.35 |
  |  Foreign      16    25       1      1.35 |
  +------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: hi nick! thanks for taking your time.

the list with the group function is a great start but is there a way of adding the mileage of the domestic cars with a trunk space of 7 (for example)

so instead of listing me all the mileages and the frequency they occur they´d add up?

so instead of domestic 7 18 (freq1) and fomestic 7 24 (freq2) we would have 1 line stating:
domestic 7 66

continuing with domestic 8 56, domestic 9 79 etc

Comment: The `groups` command (not `group`, not a function) has an option `show(none)` to suppress display of frequencies: see the `help`. For what you want you just need to create the total first with `egen mpgtotal = total(mpg), by(foreign trunk)` and then follow with `groups foreign trunk mpgtotal, show(none)`.